# Multiple Conditions In MS Excel Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the `median price (SP)` of existing homes (`NewCon="No"`) for each month in my spreadsheet. For some reason, I get an error using each of the two formulas:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(DATE(YEAR(Closing_Date),1,1)=$G2,IF(NewCon="No",SP)))}
```

Have also tried:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF(DATE(YEAR(Closing_Date),1,1)=$G2*(NewCon="No"),SP))}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Spreadsheet_Image]

Expected Outcome:

[image: Expected Outcome Cell I2 contains formula]

Comment: Image of your data and expected outcome would really help. Also, what error are you getting with each of the above?

Comment: with that date you are only looking at Jan 1st of the closing date.

Comment: For this I would use a pivot table instead.

Comment: I thought that would give all dates for the entire year?

Comment: Can you generate medians now from a pivotable, or do you mean use a work-around Scott?

Comment: nevermind, I thought that median can be done.  and no that returns only the first of january and if $G2 is not equal to that then it would not find it.  Please show what you have and what you want.

Comment: I've uploaded a snapshot of a piece of the spreadsheet and my expected outcome. I think Scott is correct on my error in my date formula. I would like to generate the median for each year (only, not month), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(17,6,SP/((YEAR(Closing_Date)=$G2)*(NewCon="No")),2)
```

Or you can use your array entered formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF((YEAR(Closing_Date)=$G2)*(NewCon="No"),SP))
```

With Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: The aggregate formula appears to work (though I do not understand it), while the median formula returns "#N/A" & yes, I did hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: With the median, did you hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter?

Comment: Yes I did use Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: This formula works to find the average price for "All" properties: {=MEDIAN(IF((YEAR(Closing_Date)=G5),SP))}, yet this returns "#N/A" when I add the NewCon criteria: {=MEDIAN(IF((YEAR(Closing_Date)=(G5))*(NewCon="No"),SP))}

Comment: `G5` should not be in `()`